# Spring Reactive API response blank body while transforming Mono<Void> to Mono<Response>

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller

I have a service call that returns Mono. Now while giving API response to user I want to send some response. I tried with flatMap as well as a map but it won't work. It gives me an empty body in response.

Here the code sample

```
    //Service Call
    public Mono<Void> updateUser(....) {
        .......... return Mono<Void>...
    }

   //Rest Controller
   @PostMapping(value = "/user/{id})
    public Mono<Response> update(......) {
        return service.updateUser(....)
                .map(r -> new Response(200, "User updated successfully"));

    }
```

When I hit the above API it gives me an empty body in response. Can anyone please help me to get body in API response?

Thank you

Comment: use the `then` or `thenReturn` operator instead of `map`.

Comment: Yes it's work fine thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wish to ignore the return value from a `Mono` or `Flux` and just trigger something next in the chain you can use either the `then` operator, or the `thenReturn` operator.

The difference is that `then` takes a `Mono` while `thenReturn` takes a concrete value (witch will get wrapped in a `Mono`.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/user/{id})
public Mono<Response> update(......) {
    return service.updateUser(....)
            .thenReturn(new Response(200, "User updated successfully"));
}
```